# nautilus: error while loading shared libraries: libtracker-data.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus

First, I cannot open my file and recycle bin icon, when I click on it, it just loads and then two seconds later there's no response.

I tried to run `nautilus` in the terminal. It then prompts with the following:

```
nautilus: symbol lookup error /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tracker-2.0/libtracker-data.so:undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_pointer"
```

There are solutions to this problem online, but before I find solutions, I make new question, I ran

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tracker-2.0/libtracker-data.so
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tracker
```

in the terminal to try to reinstall something, but the issue wasn't solved. When I run `nautilus` again, I get:

```
nautilus: error while loading shared libraries: libtracker-data.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory" .
```

In conclusion, I want to restore my file icon, I want it to react. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess that's a lesson not to go deleting system file - what is your Ubuntu version? At least on 20.04, it looks like the .so file that you deleted is part of the [libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libtracker-sparql-2.0-0)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: So have you tried reinstalling the above mentioned package (`sudo apt install --reinstall libtracker-sparql-2.0-0`)?

Comment: Thank you very much! After reinstalling libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 my icon can be opened!

Comment: For future reference: Use `dpkg-query -S name_of_file` to know which package a file is from. Looking at the error message, the problem was not caused by deleting the file, but rather by a version conflict between nautilus and tracker